# SSRS Hide/show image based on row value

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report, which has rows of exam results, exam name in one column, result in the other. If the exam name column contains a specific exam name I'd like to show an image, however, it seems to hide all the time when using the following show/hide

```
=iif(Fields!txtResultName.Value = "VR*",True,False)
```

It seems to always hide weather the VR record is there or not.

The design view looks like this:

[image: Design View]

I also have the following visibility expression on the 2nd row to hide the 'VR*' exam or any other exam if no results exists.

```
=iif(len(Fields!txtResult.Value) = 0,True,False)
```

Answer (score 1):

So first question, you want the image to be visible when `txtResultName` begins with `VR`?  Because SSRS is a little weird with visibility in that you are actually setting the expression for `Hidden` -- meaning when the conditional evaluates to the true result, the object is hidden.  I'm guessing you want to reverse the true and false values.  Secondly, you should be able to use the `Contains` or `InStr` to get this working correctly.

```
= IIF(Fields!txtResultName.Value.Contains("VR"), False, True)
```

Or with `InStr`:

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!txtResultName.Value, "VR") > 0, False, True)
```

`Contains` simply searches the entire string for the characters `VR` and shows the image when the characters are found.  `InStr` searches for the same characters but returns a value indicating the position in the string where the characters appear -- so any value greater than zero indicates that they are present in the string.

Comment: Thanks, Steve for your reply. I've tried both of those, it seems to always show now. However, still showing even if that child does not have a VR mark...

Although this has made me think. I've already got another visibility expression in place to hide any row that does not contain a grade, so technically the VR name will always be there but hidden if no result is present. How can I get the image to only show if there is a grade in the row called VR?

Comment: You would probably need to use some expression that combines the other hidden expression with the one we're working on here.  Could you add some more details to your question?  Put up the other hidden expression and maybe a screenshot of your report in design view and/or the preview view? It'll be easier to figure out with some more information on what things look like.

Comment: I thought maybe that, or somehow suppress blank records in the query, but not sure if that's possible... I've updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Steve, final solution below:

```
=iif(max(iif(Fields!txtResultName.Value="VR*", Fields!txtResult.Value,nothing)) = nothing, true, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using more then one dataset in report and you want to work on visiblity of image then do something like this
and it works

```html
 =iif((first(Fields!fk_degreeid.Value, "Btech_Gradesystem_Semresult")= "10") ,false,true)
```